# why does equals function of instance of sub class of Any return boolean value in kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, any

I was learning Any class. In the meantime, i discovered equals function of Any does not have body but if instance of sub class that does not override equals function of Any call equals function, return boolean true or false. I wonder why. Why?

Comment: The foundational classes of Kotlin are a little strange, for lack of a better word, because Kotlin can target more than just the JVM. But when targeting the JVM, for example, `Any` is actually `java.lang.Object` (which does define an implementation of `equals`, though via native code).

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. please explain in more detail.

Comment: Kotlin can target different platforms, including the JVM (i.e. the _Java Virtual Machine_, which is what Java runs on), JavaScript, and native. I've never used Kotlin to target JavaScript or native, so I have no appreciable knowledge in that domain. But when targeting the JVM any uses of `Any` are translated to `java.lang.Object`. That's a Java class within the standard Java library (Java SE) and is the root of the class hierarchy. The `java.lang.Object` class implements the `equals` method. So any time you use `Any.equals` (non-overridden) you're calling `Object.equals` (when running on JVM).